# Kile: how to use shortcut to compile the root file directly?

Tags: kile

I have several tex files to create a pdf.

The `root.tex` use `\input{}` to import other tex files.

While I'm editing other tex files, I want to compile my tex by using some shortcut instead of using mouse to switch to `root.tex` and compile it.

My question is:
Is there any shortcut that can help me compile the root.tex no matter which file I'm in in Kile?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Create a project and specify the root file in the project preferences (or let Kile guess if it gets it right).

Answer (score 10):

You can create [`projects`](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/projects.html) in Kile.

> In Kile you can create and work with projects. A project is a group of LATEX, graphic, BibTEX or other files that contain all the information that is used to build your complete document. A typical project would be a document consisting of several chapters, written in different .tex files; all of them could be included in a project, to make the whole document easier to manage. The specifications of the project are stored in a special file, with extension .kilepr.

You can then either let Kile automatically find the `root.tex` or tell it where to look and then all the build commands work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you give me a hink: which method I should use to let Kile to auto find the root.tex?

Comment: @MikeXu if your `root.tex` file starts with `\documentclass` (and no other files in the project do, then Kile should automatically find it. If you have lots of files which start with `\documentclass` and/or `root.tex` does not start with `documentclass`, then you might need to tell Kile which file is `root.tex`. It is pretty easy, just try it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try. Hmm, it did have root.tex only have the \documentclass...

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is still ending up here for a solution, you should know that now it is possible to set a master file in Kile.

Just go to:
menu > Settings, and click on entry "Define Current Document as 'Master Document'".

From then on, any compile command that you run (either from shortcuts or by clicking on a button) will have as argument the master file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like Kile Projects, you could do what I do:

At the bottom, below the `\end{document}` line, I have a line defining a shell alias that, for your case, could look somewhat like

```
alias rtx="cd home/mike/tex && pdflatex root.tex"
```

While I work in Kile, I have always a Konsole window open; at the beginning of my work session, I paste the text above into the Konsole window and then, for the rest of the day, I simply type `rtx` in the Konsole window. Or just use the up-arrow.

That could be made more sophisticated, making the alias persistent or turning it into a short shell script, but I like it exactly this way. Easy and flexible!

Comment: You may have your reasons for doing so, but compiling outside of Kile you miss at least the ability to click on errors and go to the corresponding line; also you have to constantly switch windows, which may not be so practical: it is far more convenient to just hit Ctrl+6 to run `pdflatex` than to switch to another window, compile, and switch back to Kile to continue writing.