# Compiling a file with two document classes

Tags: compiling, document-classes

Just out of curiosity: Is there a way to compile latex document with two document classes at once?

Suppose that I have a paper which start with line:
`\documentclass[preprint,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}`

But finally I would like to compile it with such line:
`\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}`

Obviously I can replace these lines and compile file twice, but I wonder if there is any trick to avoid double compilation?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5228/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create two dummy documents `final.tex` and `draft.tex`.

`preprint.tex`

```
\documentclass[preprint,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
\input{main.tex}
```

`final.tex`

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\input{myfile.tex}
```

If you are using an IDE to compile make compiling the documents easier, there may be additional hoops to jump through (e.g., [Kile: how to use shortcut to compile the root file directly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158927/kile-how-to-use-shortcut-to-compile-the-root-file-directly)).

Comment: This is still a double compilation, but in general it is nice and simple workaround.